# ARM Template resourceid() function Fails

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Please help me understand what is wrong with my Azure ARM template here, Which is very basic, takes some input arguments and prints out resourceId.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualNetworkResourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location to Deploy Azure Resources"
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "subnetRef": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

Providing the required parameters, it fails with the following Error Message.

Parameter File

```
{  
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "value": "core-services-vnet"
    },
    "virtualNetworkResourceGroupName": {
      "value": "core-networking-rg"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "value": "private"
    },
    "location": {
      "value": "westus"
    }
  }
}
```

```
$ az deployment create -n core-deploy --template-file azuredeploy.json --parameters @params.json --location westus

Deployment failed. Correlation ID: b97a7544-2814-40c0-88c9-fbaaea2bf645. The template output 'subnetRef' is not valid: The provided value 'core-networking-rg' is not valid subscription identifier. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#resourceid for usage details.
```

What Am I missing here ?

Thanks, Nag

Comment: I am not getting an error. Double check your parameter input. Edit your question and include more details on how you are getting this error.

Comment: Does the resource group `myResource-rg`? Sounds like the most likely problem

Comment: @johnHanley Updated with more details in the Question

Comment: @james It is irrespective of any resource group I try.

Comment: If the vnet is in the same resource group and providing the value as ```"value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]"``` works perfectly fine; but I need to refer to subnet in a different resource group

Comment: @NagMatukumalli does the target resource group reside in the same location?

Comment: @James, yes it does reside in the same location

Comment: @Nag please double check the resource group name for Virtual network

Comment: It give me impression that resourceId function is assuming the first argument as subscriptionId Instead of Resourcegroup, thus complaining provided value is not subscription identifier.

Comment: I had added subscriptionID in the value part as ```"value": "[resourceId(subscription().subscriptionId, parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]"``` which ends up with following error

Comment: ```The template output 'subnetRef' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': function requires fully qualified resource type 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets' as one of first three arguments for resource at resource group scope, or first two arguments for resource at subscription scope. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#resourceid for usage details..```

Comment: @NagMatukumalli  Try to use `az group deployment create -n core-deploy --template-file azuredeploy.json --parameters @params.json --location westus`? Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks @NancyXiong, That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the [deployment scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-cli#deployment-scope). You can target your deployment to either an Azure subscription or a resource group within a subscription.

In your template, the $schema `https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#` is used for resource group deployments, while the commands `az deployment create` you use is for subscription-level deployments. The schema `https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#` for subscription-level deployments is different than the schema for resource group deployments. You could get references from [creating resource groups and resources at the subscription level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/deploy-to-subscription).

In this case, you can use the commands `az group deployment create -n core-deploy --template-file azuredeploy.json --parameters @params.json --location westus` instead of `az deployment create xxx` to fix this issue.